# Render ValidationMessageFor with Font Awesome icons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I am attempting to implement form validation using Font Awesome icons in combination with the standard MVC validation process. I have written a custom ValidationMessageFor helper to achieve this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FontAwesomeValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var name = helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName));

        var builder = new TagBuilder("span");

        var modelName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        builder.MergeAttribute("data-valmsg-for", modelName);
        builder.MergeAttribute("data-valmsg-replace", bool.TrueString.ToLowerInvariant());

        if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] == null ||
            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors == null ||
            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors.Count == 0)
        {
            return !helper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled
                ? MvcHtmlString.Empty
                : MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
        }

        builder.AddCssClass("text-danger");
        builder.InnerHtml = "<i class='fa fa-exclamation'></i>";
        builder.MergeAttribute("title", helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors[0].ErrorMessage);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
    }
```

This is called in my form thus:

```
@Html.FontAwesomeValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
```

and renders this HTML by default:

```
<span data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

This seems to work fine and renders the appropriate spans on my form. However as soon as I enable client side validation my helper is no longer called, instead the standard model validation message is displayed. How can I get the client side validation to render my helper HTML? Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 3):

This could be solved to some extent with CSS. If for instance you want to prefix your validation messages with a fontawesome icon you would include the following CSS:

```
.field-validation-error:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f06a\00a0";
}
```

All validation messages are wrapped in a span tag with a class of `field-validation-error`. The above CSS will attach an exclamation icon and space before the validation text.

Answer (score 1):

Client side validation messages are displayed using jQuery.Validate.js unobtrusively. You have to define client-side jQuery adapter which will contain the logic to display font awesome and add with validate.js.